# com.apple.Installer-Progress causing missing progress bar

Tags: macos, monterey, menu-bar

I have an issue where some machines are booting up with no menu bar.  Through sleuthing I found that the "Installer Progress" app is running and holding the menu bar.  Since it is running as root I can't stop it without sudo'ing.  Rebooting the machine sometimes fixes it.

This started happening after an upgrade to 12.6.1, the highest OS the machines in question are able to run.

Any suggestions?